How to remove trailing spaces in all files except Markdown?
I use Prettier to format my code. By default Prettier removes/trims trailing whitespaces. This is a good thing but an inconvenience in Markdown files. I use trailing whitespaces in Markdown for creating line breaks. I could use <br /> tag but the parser I'm using does not accept that (does not add a line break).
In a .editorconfig file I could use
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

Do we have a similar setting for Prettier, since formatting by an editor is overridden when prettier comes in last to format the files
